# Performance of Elasticsearch facets

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have a strange situation: in my faceted query one of the facets causes the query to be executed much slower than any other facets. In general, if this particular facet is present, the query will be ~ 5 times slower regardless of how many other facets are there. The mapping for all the fields, used to calculate facets, is exactly the same.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this behavior?

Slow facet (takes ~ 1400 ms to get data back):

```
{
  "facets": {
   "postal_code": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "postal_code_untouched"
  }
}
  },
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Fast facet (takes ~ 300 ms to get the results):

```
{
  "facets": {
   "category": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "category_description_untouched"
  }
}
  },
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Mappings:

```
category_description_untouched: {
  type: string
  analyzer: keyword_lowercase
  include_in_all: false
}

postal_code_untouched: {
  type: string
  analyzer: keyword_lowercase
  include_in_all: false
}
```

Category description is just free text; the postal codes are UK postal codes, so those are like "GU51 4BE". The total number of documents in the index is 4,156,339.

Comment: Does the facet always take that long, or just on the first time it is run?  If that is a high-cardinality field, it may take a while to populate the cache on the first run.  If it's always slow...I'm not sure.

Comment: Always: the first one is always slow, the second one is always fast.

Comment: How many different postal codes and category descriptions do you have?

Comment: There are ~ 6500 unique category descriptions. I was not able to calculate number of unique postal codes: the query times out every time...